# Recorrer array json con php

Tags: php, json

necesito recorrer este array y extraer los datos heartRate y deviceNumber en variables separadas.

```
{
"bodys": {
"bikeArrays": [],
"heartRateArrays": [
{
"heartRate": "88",
"deviceNumber": "302831"
}
]
},
"status": 1
}

El codigo que estoy utilizando es el siguiente:



$url = 'http://localhost:8090/rc900/openapi/datas?deviceNumbers=302831'; 
//me devuelve el array de arriba

$json = file_get_contents($url);
$obj = json_decode($json);


$datos = $obj->bodys->heartRateArrays;
echo json_encode($datos);


?>

obtengo como resultado cuando hago echo json_encode($datos);

[{"heartRate":"58","deviceNumber":"302831"}]
```

> quisiera saber como recorrer el resultado de arriba para meterlo en
>   dos variables separadas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo asi:

```
$hearRate = $obj->bodys->heartRateArrays[0]->heartRate;
$deviceNo = $obj->bodys->heartRateArrays[0]->deviceNumber;
```

Comment: Excelente Alan, esto ha solucionado mi inconveniente.
En un principio no funcionaba ya que hearRateArrays es heartRateArrays

Answer (score 0):

Modificando un poco la respuesta de

> alanfcm

prueba de la siguiente forma:

```
$hearRate = $obj->bodys->hearRateArrays[0][heartRate];
$deviceNo = $obj->bodys->hearRateArrays[0][deviceNumber];
```

Comment: Sigue con error

Answer (score 0):

$obj = json_decode($json, true);

Conviertelo a array con el segundo parámetro $assoc = true y trabajalo como se acostumbra hacerlo con un array asociativo y foreach.

Answer (score 0):

Agregando ejemplos a la respuesta del colega Mario.

**Decodifica el JSON**

$obj = json_decode($json, true);

**Recorre el Arreglo**

```
foreach ($resultado_json as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $key2 => $value2) {
        echo $heartRate= $value2[0]['heartRate'];
        echo $deviceNumber= $value2[0]['deviceNumber'];
    };            
};

print_r($heartRate); //88
print_r($deviceNumber); //302831
```

**Almacena tus datos en Variables**

$heartRate

$deviceNumber